# Babili minifies but does not transpile

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babili

I am stuck with [babili](https://github.com/babel/babili).

I need to `transpile`, then minify the javascript that is written in `ES6`. So I installed the package using:

```
npm install babili --save-dev
```

and made `.babelrc` file containing a preset:

```
{"presets": ["es2015"]}
```

Now I tried the following command

`./node_modules/.bin/babili public/js/rt.socket.js --out-file public/test.min.js`

It does give a minified but doesn't transpile. What could be the reason for this?
`

Comment: Babili's job is to minify, not to transpile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babili does not use `.babelrc`. Per the [README](https://github.com/babel/babili#readme):

> Note that, because the `babili` command uses the default preset with `no-babelrc`, you cannot set any non-default options in the preset's plugins with this command. To do this, you can use the `babel` command with the options set in a `.babelrc`. See the preset docs for more information on how to do this.

The solution is to instead use Babel with the `babel-preset-babili` preset, as described in the [Babel preset](https://github.com/babel/babili#babel-preset) section of the README (which assumes that you've already installed Babel):

> #### Install
>
> ```sh
> npm install babel-preset-babili --save-dev
> ```
>
> #### Usage
>
> You'll most likely want to use it only in the production environment.
>   Check out the [env
>   docs](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/#env-option) for more help.
>
> > Options specific to a certain environment are merged into and overwrite non-env specific options.
>
> `.babelrc:`
>
> ```json
> {
>   "presets": ["es2015"],
>   "env": {
>     "production": {
>       "presets": ["babili"]
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Then you'll need to set the env variable which could be something like
>   `BABEL_ENV=production npm run build`

Comment: Okay. Is there a way I could pipe the output of `babel` into `babili` so that only one file gets created? I am on unix shell.

Comment: If you use the Babili preset with Babel, as described above, only one file will be created.

Comment: I have installed the babili preset with babel but do not understand how to use it.

Comment: The Babili preset works exactly like other Babel presets. Refer to the [Babel docs](http://babeljs.io/) and the [Babili README](https://github.com/babel/babili#babel-preset). If you've followed the documentation to the best of your ability, create a new question describing exactly what you've tried, including the contents of your configuration files and the commands you've typed, and the result you're getting.